# python: calling constructor from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, argument-unpacking

I'm not quite sure of the terminology here so please bear with me....

Let's say I have a constructor call like this:

```
machineSpecificEnvironment = Environment(
   TI_C28_ROOT = 'C:/appl/ti/ccs/4.1.1/ccsv4/tools/compiler/c2000',
   JSDB = 'c:/bin/jsdb/jsdb.exe',
   PYTHON_PATH = 'c:/appl/python/2.6.4',
)
```

except I would like to replace that by an operation on a dictionary provided to me:

```
keys = {'TI_C28_ROOT': 'C:/appl/ti/ccs/4.1.1/ccsv4/tools/compiler/c2000',
        'JSDB': 'c:/bin/jsdb/jsdb.exe',
        'PYTHON_PATH': 'c:/appl/python/2.6.4'}
machineSpecificEnvironment = Environment(
     ... what do I put here? it needs to be a function of "keys" ...
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
machineSpecificEnvironment = Environment(**keys)
```

Comment: In the documentation *duck*
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: various places, but the problem is knowing what to look for (and even then since there's no keyword it's tricky to search).

Try http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls for the formal function call syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a dict as an argument list by the ** notation

```
machineSpecificEnvironment = Environment(**keys)
```